# Placing returned value of a cookie in mail()

Tags: php, email, cookies

I am trying to run a script that mails a value of a set cookie. For some reason it is not working. Can someone have a look at my code and tell me what im doing wrong here?

My code looks something like this:

```
function read_cookie(){   
    if (isset($_COOKIE['Order1'])){
        $order1 = $_COOKIE['Order1'];
        print $order1;
    }
}

$to = example@email.com;
$subject = "Your order";
$message = '<html><body>
    <p>This is your order: ' . read_cookie() . '</p>
    </body></html>'
$headers = "From: XXL-TShirts" . "\r\n
    Reply-To: no-reply " . "\r\n
    MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The mail() function itself seems to work. I am getting emails when I use it. The value from the read_cookie() just wont return, even though the value seems to print outside the mail() function...

Comment: "just wont return" --- because you don't `return` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return it as @zerkms said like this:

```
function read_cookie(){   
    if (isset($_COOKIE['Order1'])){
        $order1 = $_COOKIE['Order1'];
        return $order1;
    }
}
```